# Explain meaning of column Schedule Status on the Index Management admin page

Tags: magento2, cron, indexing, indexer, magento-cron

There are 2 columns on the Index Management page: **Status** and **Schedule status**.
Could you please provide detailed explanation what does each combination of values mean?

For example:

| Status | Schedule status | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ready | Idle (0 in backlog) | It means: Indexer is ready. 0 not-processed items in changelog. |
| Processing | Suspended (0 in backlog) | info about it |

[image: Index Management grid]

I am confused by conbinations from the picture (Ready + Working (0 in backlog))

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, the Index Management page shows the status and schedule status of the various indexes in your store. Here is a detailed explanation of what each combination of values means:

***1.Status:***

- Reindex Required: This means that the index needs to be updated
  because some changes have been made to the data it indexes.
- Processing: This means that the index is currently being updated.
- Ready: This means that the index has been updated and is ready to be
  used.
- Disabled: This means that the index has been disabled and is not
  being updated.

***2-Schedule Status:***

- Update On Save: This means that the index is updated automatically
  when a change is made to the data it indexes.
- Scheduled: This means that the index is scheduled to be updated at a
  specific time.
- Scheduled (not executed): This means that the scheduled update has
  not yet been executed.
- Disabled: This means that the index is not scheduled to be updated
  automatically.

Here are some common combinations of Status and Schedule Status and what they mean:

**Reindex Required / Update On Save:** This means that the index needs to be updated and will be updated automatically when a change is made to the data it indexes.

**Processing / Scheduled (not executed):** This means that the index is currently being updated and a scheduled update has also been set.

**Ready / Disabled:** This means that the index has been updated and is ready to be used, but it is not being updated automatically.

**Disabled / Disabled:** This means that the index is disabled and is not being updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for such a long answer! But values you mentioned in  2-Schedule Status column don't exist. As u can see on image in the answer: there IDLE, SUSPENDED etc. 
It seems they lives  in `\Magento\Framework\Mview\View\StateInterface`